# Graphics.set_font Ocaml

Tags: graphics, ocaml

i m using the Graphics.set_font function to change the font of a text like

```
Graphics.set_font "-*-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--50-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1";
```

my question is : What is the default font used by Ocaml ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not intimately familiar with the Graphics library, much less its source code. But a cursory search reveals the following:

On UNIX, the [`DEFAULT_FONT` is set to "fixed"](https://github.com/ocaml/graphics/blob/a116ac59b09f4aa723d9450cb3dd5f9fd9cfe666/src/unix/libgraph.h#L62), which presumably means it will use whatever is configured as your system's fixed-width font.

On Windows, the `gr_reset` function [loads the "Courier" font](https://github.com/ocaml/graphics/blob/a116ac59b09f4aa723d9450cb3dd5f9fd9cfe666/src/win32/open.c#L151).